# UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle() deprecated in iOS 9

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, statusbar, ios9

I have been using

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle()
```

In my appDelegate and it has worked fine, but since iOS 9, this method is deprecated and I can't find an alternative.

I want to change the statusbar style to .LightContent for my whole application,
but the only suggestion xCode gives me is to handle this in every VC separately with;

```
override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .LightContent
}
```

Has anyone an idea how to do this for the whole application?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have the same problem. For all my view controllers in the application I use `BaseViewController` superclass, where I set this style.

Comment: @AlexanderKaraberov Thanks for your comment, I was thinking about your method before, but I wasn't sure if that was the best way, but it seems like the best option for now.

Comment: If you are using the `UINavigationController` then here is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32730211/how-we-can-set-the-light-content-style-of-status-bar-in-ios-9-for-whole-applicat/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Status Bar Style in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38740648/how-to-set-status-bar-style-in-swift-3)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I think I have found a solution.
I ended up setting the

`View controller-based status bar appearance` boolean to `NO`

In my info.plist file.

[image: Info.Plist]

Then I went to my target's `General settings -> Deployment info` and changed the dropdown option
`Status Bar Style` to `Light` instead of `Default`

[image: Change Status Bar Style to Light]

This changed the statusbar style to `Light` for my whole application, just what I wanted.

I Hope this helps!

Comment: So there are two ways to do it.  Either do the above and set View controller-based status bar appearance to NO and then set the Deployment Info to light, OR set View controller-based status bar appearance to YES and override in your view controller with  `override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
        return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
        
    }
`

Comment: Status Bar Style's dropdown is missing in xcode 7.2. Where I can find it? @Rick?

Comment: @Rick I think it was right. See my screenshot here https://www.dropbox.com/s/m40nwswf6wy8uh5/Screenshot%202016-02-19%2014.12.39.png?dl=0

Comment: @SonicMaster Let me have a look and I will let you know

Comment: Ah, I think I know what's wrong. That dropdown only shows if I change my Deployment Info's target into Universal. It disappear if you use specific target (ipad/iphone). Thank you so much, @Rick

Comment: @SonicMaster Ah now I get it, no problem, thanks to you aswel!

Comment: what I find pretty stupid is that, if I want to have the `.lightContent` as default and change to `.default` to just few view controllers, I can't...

Comment: The goal is to dynamically change the status bar style ... your answer is just a basic static approach that everyone knows about.

Answer (score 11):

In swift 3.

In your view controller:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
}
```

If you wish when the app run your launch screen also has the status bar in lightContent then:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

In Swift 3 is like that:

```
 UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
```

Comment: It's the same thing, deprecated

Answer (score 3):

To dynamically update **UIStatusBarStyle** on view controllers use this method

**this will also remove deprecated warning**

***'setStatusBarStyle:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use -[UIViewController preferredStatusBarStyle]***

for calling

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:style];
```

**Let's Get Started**

**Objective - C**

define **UtilityFunction**

```
+(void)setStatusBarStyle:(UIStatusBarStyle )style {    
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:style forKey:@"UIStatusBarStyle"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

over-ride this method in your **BaseViewController**

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    UIStatusBarStyle style = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"UIStatusBarStyle"];
    return style;
}
```

set UIStatusBarStyle value for the **AnyViewController** using a UtilityFunction like below:

```
[UtilityFunctions setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault];

// call below code for preferred style
[self preferredStatusBarStyle];
```

**Swift 4.0**

define **UtilityFunction**

```
class func setPreferedStyle(style:UIStatusBarStyle)->Void {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(style, forKey: "UIStatusBarStyle")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}
```

over-ride this method in your **BaseViewController**

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    if let style: UIStatusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle(rawValue:UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "UIStatusBarStyle")) {
        return style
    }
    return UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
}
```

set UIStatusBarStyle value for the **AnyViewController** using a UtilityFunction like below:

```
Utility.setPreferedStyle(style: .lightContent)

// call below code for preferred style
preferredStatusBarStyle()
```

Comment: oc version  not woking at all

Comment: It doesn't seem a very clean solution though

Answer (score 1):

This worked fine for me in Xcode 7.

In AppDelegate:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent
```

Comment: This works, but it is deprecated in iOS 9.0.  Still fires a warning and will quit working in some future iOS iteration.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5, iOS 13.5+**

I'm gonna make a recap that I hope it's gonna be helpful.

#1: **General solution without using `preferredStatusBarStyle`**

To answer the question, *if we don't want to care about exceptions screens* and not use the `preferredStatusBarStyle` property from view controllers as Apple recommends, I think that indeed setting the `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `false` and changing the `Status Bar Style` under `General settings -> Deployment info` to light, as @Rick already recommended, is the way to go.

#2: **Using `preferredStatusBarStyle`**

For my case, I wanted to be able to have the `UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent` as default, but with some screens having the `UIStatusBarStyle.default`; and in these kind of cases, the solution #1 isn't possible.

Since also having a general extension to `UIViewController` that allows to change the default value isn't obviously possible for this property, the only and best way to proceed in these cases if we don't want to use deprecated methods, is via **inheritance**.

So, a possibility is to have a general `BaseViewController` (and also the `BaseNavigationController` if you use one) that you controller inherits from, that sets the `preferredStatusBarStyle` to `.lightContent`.

With this approach, now you can simply set the style to `default` where needed, while maintaining the `lightContent` as default.

Answer (score 0):

for those still working with Swift 3 in Xcode 8:

( slightly different to Marlon Ruiz's answer above, not an override function, but within viewDidLoad )

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This is the new way in AppDelegate:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: true)
```

Comment: If you use this in the AppDelegate it still says its been depricated.

Comment: it is also depricated.

Comment: This is the same thing

Answer (score -2):

In info.plist, set:
`View controller-based status bar appearance` boolean to `NO`

In app delegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, use function parameter `application` (and not the `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` or simillary the `UIApplication.sharedApplication()` in swift) to set this like so:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    application.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

Comment: Any comment on why downwoting this answer? It works for me.

Comment: As some of the users have already answered, doing it this way is not recommended because directly accessing the statusBarStyle variable is deprecated. It will show you a warning, and it might break your app in the future.