# How we can set the Light Content style of Status Bar in iOS 9 for whole application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uistatusbar

I want to apply Light Content style to the whole application.

Following method is deprecated in iOS 9 without the replacement method.

> -setStatusBarStyle:animated:
>
> Sets the style of the status bar, optionally animating the transition
>   to the new style.

Is working in the `AppDelegate` like as :

*Swift 1.2 Code :*

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: true)
```

But when I upgrade my project to iOS 9/Swift 2 they are giving me warning message about :

```
<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
<Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
<Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
```

So as per the solution from the [apple forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13683) and from this answer [CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0 Error only on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32236204/cgcontextsavegstate-invalid-context-0x0-error-only-on-device)

So, I have removed the property `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` from the `info.plist` file as per the solution.

Now the situation is that **How we can set the Light Content style of Status Bar in iOS 9 for whole application?**

From the forum :

[image]

I don't want to set the Light Content for each and every view.

Any suggestions?

Objective-C should have the same issue.

Comment: Are you using UINavigationController?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can save yourself a lot of work by using a UINavigationController and setting its navigation bar's `barStyle` to `.Black`. You only have to do this once; you can do it in the storyboard editor.

This will automatically turn your status bar's style to `.LightContent` as long as this UINavigationController is in command.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will check and let you know.

Comment: Woooa! This is working fine :) Thanks a lot. Can you suggest what we have to do if there is no `UINavigationController`?

Comment: In that case you would need to put your entire interface into a custom parent container view controller that serves as the root view controller of the whole app, and implements `preferredStatusBarStyle`. Either that or just bite the bullet and implement `preferredStatusBarStyle` everywhere.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Please update the answer with this statement. So anyone can get help from your answer.

Comment: [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];

Comment: For those of you who are using a splitView controller, make sure you set the preferredBarStyle on that ...

Answer (score 0):

You can also used:
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent. It also works in swift3.

Comment: It should still work but I believe it has been deprecated.

Comment: In swift3 it works, I am using it in my current project.

Comment: It's Deprecated from iOS 9.0 https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622988-statusbarstyle