# StatusBarStyle not working as expected on iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode7

I am trying to get the following StatusBarStyle on my swift app :

[image]

My AppDelegate uses a UINavigationController as follows

```
self.nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller!)
```

So I tried to set the UIBarStyle to Black as follows :

```
    self.nav?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
```

However, this results in the following :

[image]

BTW, on my Info.plist, I have the following set

```
<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
<string>UIStatusBarStyleDefault</string>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

And those settings result in the desired statusbar style on the LaunchScreen but not on the other screens.

I even tried adding the following method to all the VCs inside the UINavigationController

```
override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyle.Default
}
```

But that results in the following status bar style :

[image]

What is the best way to have the desired status bar style in the case where you have a UINavigationController on iOS 9?

Additionally, if I remove the plist entry and set

```
 self.nav?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
```

in AppDelegate, I get the following result :

[image: white_text_on_gray_background_status_bar_style]

Additionally, I removed all the places where backgroundColor was being set except the following in AppDelegate (colorOne is the deepBlue color I want on the status bar)

```
self.window?.backgroundColor = colorOne
```

And when I did this, I get a light blue color on the status bar, which is the closest color to the deep blue color I need on the status bar as seen here

[image: black_text_on_light_blue_status_bar]

Comment: Check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32730211/how-we-can-set-the-light-content-style-of-status-bar-in-ios-9-for-whole-applicat and answer. You have to remove the plist entry.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. When I remove the plist entry and set self.nav?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black in AppDelegate, I get the following result :  http://i.stack.imgur.com/tEcOm.png

Comment: Are you using storyboards?

Comment: I do have VCs in storyboards but I am not setting any properties on them in the IB. All the properties are getting set programmatically.

Comment: Setting the appearance property (that way it affects everything) is the easier way to go about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In appDelegate use:

```
  UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
  UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false
```

Obviously you can use any UIColor you want...

Comment: Wow!! Thanks!! That was a lifesaver!!

Answer (score 0):

i hope this may help you..

if you need a specific color, how you do it with RGB is the best option:

```
  UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 5.0, green: 8.0, blue: 9.0, alpha:0.5)
```

if its not working then try this:
    var navigationBarAppearace = UINavigationBar.appearance()

```
    navigationBarAppearace.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    navigationBarAppearace.barTintColor = UIColor(red:15/255.0, green:  167/255.0, blue: 216/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```