# Xcode console warnings since Xcode 7

Tags: ios, swift

if I start my app (ios 9 with Swift 2) in xcode 7, I get this warnings at beginning:

> Oct  9 10:45:11  AppName[2866] : CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
>   Oct  9 10:45:11  AppName[2866] : CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
>   Oct  9 10:45:11  AppName[2866] : CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.

What can I do to solve this warnings?

Comment: This is a bug in Xcode see here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13683

Comment: okay, so i can ignore this and have to wait for an update?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set CG\_CONTEXT\_SHOW\_BACKTRACE environmental variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31872650/how-can-i-set-cg-context-show-backtrace-environmental-variable)

Answer (score 4):

It seems like that you are setting the corner radius(working with layers)  of a view.

Solution 1:

Set environmental variable via menu: Product-> Scheme->Edit Scheme. In "Run" item, locate "Arguments" tab, you'll see "Environmental Variables" in the tab, Add `CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE` and set its value to YES.

Solution 2:-
If above solutions does not work for you, then remove the UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance from Info.plist.

Comment: Solution 1 does not work. Solution 2 works fine -> no warnings, but now is the font color auf the status bar black and not white

Comment: @Ghost108 You can check for how to set statusbar to light content http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32730211/how-we-can-set-the-light-content-style-of-status-bar-in-ios-9-for-whole-applicat