# How can I change my status bar text color. Screenshot attached

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationbar, uistatusbar, ios-statusbar

I want to change status bar text color to customer color like screenshot attached.

I have used this to make it light content -

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

But text color not changing. Can anyone help?

[image: Status bar screenshot]

Comment: check out `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios-7`.

Comment: @iAviator Already checked this answer but its not changing status bar text color to pink.

Comment: But the answer in the thread is the only correct answer. Since you can not change the color of the text it self.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is [Apple Guidelines/Instruction](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-bars/status-bars/) about status bar change. Only Dark & light (while & black) are allowed in status bar. It does not allow to set a color (pink, as shown in your image) in status bar.

*Here is - How to change status bar style:*

If you want to set status bar style, application level then set `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `NO` in your `.plist' file.

if you wan to set status bar style, at view controller level then follow these steps:

1. Set the `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `YES` in the `.plist` file, if you need to set status bar style at UIViewController level only.
2. In the viewDidLoad add function - `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate`
3. override preferredStatusBarStyle in your view controller.

-

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

Set value of .plist according to status bar style setup level.
[image]

You can set background color for status bar during application launch or during viewDidLoad of your view controller.

```
extension UIApplication {

    var statusBarView: UIView? {
        return value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView
    }

}

// Set upon application launch, if you've application based status bar
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        return true
    }
}


or 
// Set it from your view controller if you've view controller based statusbar
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }

}
```

Here is result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Set the `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `YES` in the `.plist` file.

In the `viewDidLoad` method, do a

```
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
```

Add the following method:

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{ 
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your application will support In your application's **Info.plist**, set **"View controller-based status bar appearance"** to `NO`.

In **appDelegate.swift**, Inside the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function, add:

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
```

Best answer is described here : [How to set Status Bar Style in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38740648/how-to-set-status-bar-style-in-swift-3)

Comment: Setter for 'statusBarStyle' was deprecated in iOS 9.0: Use -[UIViewController preferredStatusBarStyle]

Answer (score 0):

Text color of status bar could be white or black.