# How to change Status Bar color to black programmatically

Tags: swift3, statusbar

There are many posts on this topic, yet I can't find one that works.

I have a View Controller that is not embedded in a Navigation Controller.  I would like to change the status bar color to black.

This is my latest attempt [How to set Status Bar Style in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38740648/how-to-set-status-bar-style-in-swift-3)

1. Change in info.plist the row View controller-based status bar appearance and set it to NO
2. Change in appDelegate.swift in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions `UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent`

Answer (score 0):

1. Add "View controller-based status bar appearance" - YES in your info.plist.
2. Add "Status bar style" - UIStatusBarStyleLightContent in your info.plist if you want the default view controller status bar to be light.
3. override preferredStatusBarStyle to default/light like so:

   ```
   class UIExampleViewController: UIViewController {

     override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
     return .lightContent
     }

   }
   ```

Comment: I'm afraid I've tried that.  The return value should be .default, which returns dark, but even with that no luck.  Strange.

Comment: Add View controller-based status bar appearance - YES in your info.plist.

Comment: I've already done that as well. I'm on XCode 8.3, so I'm pretty sure it's not a bug at this point.

Comment: Are you sure you did all three steps mentioned above? and that the viewcontroller swift file is connected to your xib? also, make sure to CMD clean your project before trying again.

Comment: Raxel.. I just noticed.  When you ovverride you specify a var and not a func?

Comment: Yes, exactly like i did, preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle is the var you want to override