# UIStatusBar style consistent with UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uistatusbar

Just to study the UI of `UINavigationBar` and `UIStatusBar`, I changed the Navigation Bar Style to Black, and unchecked the Bar visibility, i.e. Shows Navigation Bar, but the `UIStatusBar` style didn't change to `lightContent`.

It seems that if we hide the navigation bar, the status bar style doesn't change depending on the navigation bar's style, it always takes the default - i.e. black - text and we have to change the status bar style explicitly.

Is there any method or variable we need to set to keep it dependent on the navigation bar style even if it's hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to my knowledge, there is no built-in setting that automatically detects the navigation bar's visibility *and* changes the status bar accordingly. If you want to achieve that, override `preferredStatusBarStyle` in your view controller:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    guard let navBarStyle = navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle else {
        return .default
    }

    switch navBarStyle {
    case .black, .blackTranslucent: return .lightContent
    default: return .default
    }
}
```

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47750574/3151675) describes, you should set the **View controller-based status bar appearance** in your **Info.plist** to **YES**.

Comment: I'll surely give it a try and get back to you on this. Thanks for the answer