# How to change the status bar style when a view controller is loading?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uikit

I am able to hide the status bar on the launch screen by setting `Status bar is initially hidden` to `YES` in Info.plist and then I want to show it on my first view controller with a `.lightContent` style.

However `UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent` is deprecated since iOS 9 (so I don't want to use it) and using the following code give me a black status bar on my first view controller.

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

**How can I change the status bar style when my first view controller load?**

I am trying to find a global solution like `UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent` since I don't really want to set the status bar style for every view controller.
I have tested the solutions with `View controller-based status bar appearance` set to `YES` and `NO`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38740648/how-to-set-status-bar-style-in-swift-3

Comment: Already tried all the solutions but my status bar stay black and I don't want to use the deprecated solution. I am also not sure if the 'hack' solution is good to use.

Comment: Is your first view controller nested inside a UINavigationController? The UINavgationController is known to not ask its childController for the  `preferredStatusBarStyle` property

Comment: @Frederik yes it is, I did not think about that. Do you know how I can change the status bar style of a view controller nested in a navigation controller?

Comment: @adrgrondin Off the top of my head, one way is to subclass the `UINavigationController` and override its `preferredStatusBarStyle` property to delegate onto the `topViewController`. This is not the most elegant solution, but the only one I can think of right now.

Comment: @Frederik thank you for this first way to do it! I will try it and try to see if I can find other ways to do it since I now know where the problem is.

Comment: @Frederik is correct. Just to add, though, you don't need to subclass `UINavigationController` to achieve this; you can add an extension to `UINavigationController` which overrides `prefersStatusBarHidden` and `preferredStatusBarStyle`. That should work fine (as long as you set `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `YES` in your info.plist).

Comment: @PeteMorris thank you for this, all will try that!

Comment: It now works, I used the extension approach! You can answer the question or I can answer it, explain the problem and how to solve it.

Comment: @PeteMorris Nice touch, I wasn't aware that you could override the instance property in an extension. @adrgrondin Another solution, if you don't need the different view controllers inside the navigation controller to change the status bar, i.e. if you only need the `.lightContent` in your app, you can change the `barStyle` on the UINavigationBar to be `.black` and then change the `barTintColor` to your preferred colour, in order to achieve the same. This can be done in the storyboard, if you use that.

Comment: @Frederik thank you for this other approach!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem you're experiencing is that `UINavigationController` *doesn't* defer the choice of status bar to its view controllers.

Instead, for a navigation controller, the status bar style can be set by adjusting the `barStyle` property of its `navigationBar`.

If it is set to a black style, then the status bar will be light style:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
```

Note, that this will also change the color of the `navigationBar`, however you can still set the bar's colour to whatever you want using `barTintColor`:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .purple
```

If you want to make a global change, so that *all* instances of `UINavigationController` use the same status bar style (useful if you've got multiple tabs all of which use a navigation controller), then you can add an extension on `UINavigationController` and override the `preferredStatusBarStyle` property:

```
extension UINavigationController {
    open override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }
}
```

A final option, is to defer the choice to the view controllers in the navigation controller's stack.

To do that, override the `childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle` property of your navigation controller extension and have it return the `topViewController`:

```
extension UINavigationController {
    open override var childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle: UIViewController? {
        return topViewController
    }
}
```

In this case, you'll need to override `preferredStatusBarStyle` in all of your view controllers (not the optimal approach, but it's an option if you need this granular level of control on a per-child-controller basis).

All of these solutions require that your `View controller-based status bar appearance` key in Info.plist is set to `YES`.