# Setter for 'statusBarStyle' was deprecated in iOS 9.0: Use -[UIViewController preferredStatusBarStyle]

Tags: swift

How do I rewrite the code snippet according to this;
Setter for 'statusBarStyle' was deprecated in iOS 9.0: Use -[UIViewController preferredStatusBarStyle]

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
                    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: 
       [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
       FirebaseApp.configure()
       UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

        return true
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38740648/how-to-set-status-bar-style-in-swift-3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Status Bar Style in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38740648/how-to-set-status-bar-style-in-swift-3)

Answer (score 0):

This is the new method for status bar styles

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {     
      return .lightContent
}
```