# iPhone 5/SE show white statusbar, iPhone 6/7 show black statusbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, simulator

I was using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];` before, which was working fine, but is deprecated in iOS 9.0.

Following this:
[UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle() deprecated in iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32501305/uiapplication-sharedapplication-setstatusbarstyle-deprecated-in-ios-9)

in the project settings under "Deployment Info" I selected "Light" as "Status Bar Style".
Checking my Info.plist file, I also have "View controller-based status bar appearance" set to NO.

Now the "small" iPhones 5S/SE will correctly show a white statusbar, but iPhone 6(+)/7(+) will show a black statusbar.

How can I fix this?

[solved]

Actually, after finding this: [Status Bar showing black text, only on iPhone 6 iOS 8 simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869178/status-bar-showing-black-text-only-on-iphone-6-ios-8-simulator?rq=1)

I was able to work it out. I had to put either launch images for the non-working iphone models, or what I now did, use a launch storyboard. Now everything is white statusbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, after finding this:
[Status Bar showing black text, only on iPhone 6 iOS 8 simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869178/status-bar-showing-black-text-only-on-iphone-6-ios-8-simulator?rq=1)

I was able to work it out. I had to put either launch images for the non-working iphone models, or what I now did, use a launch storyboard. Now everything is white statusbar.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to go on your project general setting and set the status bar style light and than go to info `Info.plist` file and set "View controller-based status bar appearance" set to NO. if it will not work than you have to make object of UIStatusbar in ViewControllers like this.

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }
```

Call `preferredStatusBarStyle` in view did load.

Answer (score 1):

**For Swift.**

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
  return .lightContent
}
```

**For Objective c**

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

**Using Xcode**

1.Go to **Project** ==> **Target**.

2.Set **Status Bar Style** to **Light**.

3.Set **View controller-based status bar appearance equal** to **NO** in **Info.plist**.